# replicar datos de una tabla a otra con diferentes instancias y bases de datos, ya linkeadas

Tags: sql-server, trigger

estoy haciendo un trigger que me replique el insert en otra tabla de otra base de datos de una instancia distinta ya linkeadas y comunicadas entre si.

este es el trigger:
ALTER trigger [dbo].[replicaCheckInOut]
on [dbo].[CheckInOut]
after insert
as
SET IDENTITY_INSERT OFIASIS.dbo.TWREGI_RELO ON;
insert into OFIASIS.dbo.TWREGI_RELO (ID_REGI,TI_DOCU,NU_DOCU_IDEN,CO_EMPR,FE_REGI_RELO,NU_HRAS,CO_CENT_COST,CO_ORDE_SERV,CO_RELO,DE_OBSE,ST_TRAN,DE_OBSE_LOGS,CO_USUA_CREA,FE_USUA_CREA)
select TOP 1 CheckInOutId,'',right ('000000' + UserDeviceId,8),DispositivoId,FechaCompleta,+ REPLACE (CONVERT(VARCHAR,HoraMinuto,108),':',''),'','','','','','',status,InsertDate
from inserted
SET IDENTITY_INSERT OFIASIS.dbo.TWREGI_RELO OFF;

el insert :

INSERT INTO CheckInOut
            (UserDeviceId,DispositivoId,CIOTDeviceId,FechaCompleta,Fecha,TiempoCompleto,HoraMinuto,TiempoMinutos,Hora,Minuto,Segundo,status,InsertDate)
            VALUES 
            ('123','6','1','2020-04-13 20:58:15','2020-04-13','20:58:15','20:58','350','19','25','00',1,GETDATE())

al ejecutar el insert a la tabla CheckInOut la cual me replicara la data a la BD y la tabla que quiero me sale el siguiente mensaje
Msg 1088, Level 16, State 11, Procedure replicaCheckInOut, Line 28
Cannot find the object "OFIASIS.dbo.TWREGI_RELO" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Según el error no encuentra el objeto, **porque no existe o no tienes permisos**.

Dices que ya tienes una instancia linkeada y comunicada. ¿Estás seguro de que funciona correctamente?

La otra cosa que no entiendo y es raro, y no se si te funcionará, es el identity. ¿Porqué utilizas una columna identity, si luego intentas desactivarla en cada inserción? Elimina la identidad de la columna y así no tienes que quitar y establecer en cada inserción. Además identity no te asegura que la columna sea única, y te puede generar errores, que tienes que tratar y deshacer la inserción, en la base de datos original, con todo lo que se haya desencadenado.

Según la documentación de Set Identity_Insert, espera un nombre cualificado de 3 partes y no de 4. Base de datos, esquema, nombre de tabla.

Además el usuario debe de disponer de permisos al menos, para realizar un Alter a la tabla.

[Set Identity_Insert](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Como no has puesto el esquema de la tabla, no te puedo brindar más ayuda, sobre como eliminar la especificación de identidad.

[Remover columna Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230257/remove-identity-from-a-column-in-a-table)